# Left Join with count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

Excuse Me ALL...

I am Newbie with problem in left join with count

Structure Table A:

**Structure Table B:**

```
----------------------
|Branch_code   | NIK
----------------------
'IDJB001BEC', '1300001'
'IDJB001BEC', '1300002'
'IDPA001PPA', '1300003'
'IDJK001MAG', '1300004'
'IDJB001BEC', '1300005'
'IDJB001BEC', ''
'IDBTNCTR', ''
```

**Structure Table C :**

```
|branch_code|
'IDBE001BGK'
'IDBE002BGK'
'IDBTNCTR'
'IDJB001BEC'
'IDJK001HO'
'IDJK001MAG'
'IDJK001MPI'
'IDJK002MCL'
'IDJK002MPB'
'IDJK003KDY'
```

sample I hope from results like this :

```
|Branch_code|count|
'IDJK001MAG'  0
'IDJK001MPI'  0
'IDJK002MCL'  3
'IDJK002MPB'  5
'IDJK003KDY'  4
```

Notes: the zero still show from field "count" although the row is null / zero.

thanks Master

Comment: where did table a go?

Comment: Thanks Master... the query is great !! it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see what you did wrong, since you didn't post your query, but this should get you what you need:

```
SELECT 
c.branch_code, 
COUNT(b.nik) 
FROM tablec c 
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON c.branch_code = b.branch_code 
GROUP BY c.branch_code
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26f6c/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.branch_code, COUNT(b.nik) 
FROM tablec c 
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON c.branch_code, b.branch_code 
GROUP BY c.branch_code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.branch_code,count(a.nik) as nik_count from table a left join table b
on a.branch_code=b.branch_code

group by a.branch_code
```